# how to run multiple cross platform web application on the same server using different ports?

Tags: node.js, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee, rocket.chat

I am running a java web application on tomcat 7.0, which is setup on media temple Ubuntu 16.04 server. The application is running on port 8080, and I have a domain which is binded to the port.
e.g. public-ip-of-server:8080   xyz.com
Now, I want to run a node js application (rocket-chat) on the same Linux server using port 3000. I have configured the whole application, and the application is running on localhost:3000/  but when I am trying to access the application using public IP of the server (e.g. public-ip:3000/), I am not able to access it.

I have allowed the traffic on port 3000 using command,

```
ufw allow 3000
```

I also edited apache2.conf,

```
ProxyPass /rocketchat http://public-ip-of-server:3000/ 
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so LoadModule proxy_http_module
modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

but after changing this parameter I am not able to restart the apache2 service.
so I revert back the changes.

what should I do to run both the application (java and node js) on the same Linux server ? can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Ubuntu server so httpd.conf is not present there, so I have created another file, in sites-available folder of apache2.(e.g xyz.conf).
I have two domain which pointing to the same media temple name server,
I used one domain for pointing tomcat application on port 8080 and another domain for node js application on port 3000, by making virtual host in xyz.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  xyz.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
     ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  abc.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

After this I enabled proxy mode using command :

```
sudo a2enmod proxy
```

And also make this xyz.conf file as site configuration file, using command,

```
sudo a2ensite xyz.conf
```

It will ask you to reload the apache2 service, 
just reload it and restart,

```
e.g sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

The problem resolved by forwarding the request, which is received on port 80 of apache2, to tomcat:8080 and nodejs:3000, by creating virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind nodejs app to interface `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Apache configuration, you should use the localhost instead of public ip. So instead of:

```
ProxyPass /rocketchat http://public-ip-of-server:3000/
```

use:

```
ProxyPass /rocketchat http://localhost:3000/
```